# ReactNative custom port support for run-android command, McAfee workaround

Tags: react-native

I am trying to configure react native for windows for android app development but I am unable to use port 8081 as it is used by McAfee agent on my laptop.
I am able to start node js server on different port (8090)

```
react-native start --port=8090
```

But when I run the command:

```
react-native run-android
```

I am unable to specify port option. Looks to be that it is hardcoded with 8081.

Is there anyway I can start react-native run-android for custom port(8090) port on windows?
I am completely new to reactnative and following below link to configure sample Awesomeproject for android on windows.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

Answer (score 16):

There is a small work around for this. Anyone running this on a physical device(*or even otherwise*) can restart their adb session using a different port.

eg.

```
react-native start --port=1234
```

On a different cmd/terminal window.

```
react-native run-android
```

After which I am greeted by these messages.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 22.589 secs
Running C:\SDK/platform-tools/adb -s VY0025160560725694 reverse tcp:8081 
tcp:8081
```

This runs it on default reverse port of **8081**, which is ***blocked by McAfee.***

**Work around:**

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:1234
```

**Note:** You may have to kill and re-open the app.

Currently I am unable to provide an answer for an emulated device since I do not have one installed on my system. But the steps should be similar.

Comment: you saved my day @XChikuX.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Thanks for your comment and upvote. It made my day.

Answer (score 5):

Was setting up RN with android emulator. Had the same problem with company's laptop with McAfee installed and 8081 port occupied. 3 things i did to make it work.

1. run the packager server in a different port as you mentioned above, like `8090` port: `react-native start --port=8090`.
2. i use android emulator(VD), so i need to change the VD's debug server by:  **cmd+M in the emulator, Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device, enter ‘localhost:8081’**. If you connect a real android device, this step may be skipped.
3. Last thing to do is to forward the request in our local VD’s 8081 port to our machine’s 8090 port which runs the packager server by doing: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8090`

More about [adb reverse](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/252586941934d23073a8d167ec240b221062505f).

Now you should be able to change your index.android.js and hit r twice or cmd+M -> Reload to reload the VD.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround that works (I am on Linux, but it should work on Windows also).

In a Terminal tab, from the project root, I run :

```
react-native start --port=8082
```

This kicks Node up on port **8082**. 
Then, I launch the app using :

```
react-native run-android
```

Once the app is launched, I update the development server's **url** and **port** to match the settings above ([Cf. this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38117960/877353) if you don't know how).

It works !!

Answer (score 2):

**Finally It Worked!** I also faced the same issue where my 8081 port was being used by McAfee and after reading and trying all the solution only the following steps worked for me where I able to run my project on 8088

```
Steps :

1. react-native init myproject(create myproject using react-native cli) then cd myproject(move to myproject)
2. open android studio - ctrl + R => Replace 8081 to 8088 from every file.
3. react-native run-android(simulator should be running).
4. Check your local IP ex : ipconfig in windows will give your IP
5. Check yourIP:8088 in your browser => It wil show(React Native packager is running.)
6. At this time in your simulator you will get 403 forbidden error or package manager not running error
7. Ok, Now you need to point your simulator to 8088 instead of 8081, So on your simulator type cntrl + m  => Dev settings => Debugging => Set IP eg : yourIP:8080
8. Now stop package manager.
9. Now remove .babelsrc from your project.
10. Rerun the react-native run-android(If everything goes fine it will work).
```

I know its not the best way to solve this problem but until facebook team is not giving any better solution for it this may be a good approach since 8081 is hard coded everywhere.

**Note :** In some cases I have seen white screen comes without any error. For this issue please make sure that you have removed initially generated **.babelsrc**.
and stop server and restart should solve this issue.

Comment: this saved the day!

Answer (score 2):

For this

```
react-native start --port=1234
```

U just need to do this

```
react-native run-android --port=1234
```

That's it, worked for me.
update port for both commands, they should be same.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported, but there appears to be an active and open issue regarding this as well, but unfortunately the core team hasn't had a chance to merge in the PR...
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1429

This has also been reported on Product Pains, so be sure to up-vote it there...
https://productpains.com/post/react-native/allow-packager-port-to-be-configurable-change-from-8081/

Right now, it may be easier to change the port McAfee runs on. Sorry

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is the only option looks for now..unless they add support for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me. I was trying to run in 8082 port

`npx react-native run-android --port 8082`

or

`npx react-native start --port 8082`