# React Native "Could not connect to development server."

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native

I know this already has been asked a few times, but no solution has worked for me. In fact, sometimes it does connect and my app runs on the device, but one or two attempts later, with no change, it suddenly does not. My app always runs in the emulator.

I've set my IP in AppDelegate.m and RCTWebsocketExecutor.m. I've set App Transport Security Settings to "Allow Arbitrary Loads" and even set it to allow my IP. My app is using the [react-native-storage](https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage) to store a user, not sure if that could cause any problems while testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a network problem. I used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to solve my problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the way you are using ngrok ?
I believe I am facing the same issue....

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to trigger the **developer's menu** entering :

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

In **Dev Settings** > **Debug server host & port for device**, I entered the local IP of my machine followed by port 8081, i.e. `192.168.0.1:8081`.

To get my local IP address, I used the `ifconfig` command, and I locate the **inet** field value of the Wifi interface, i.e. **wlp2s0**.

I hope this helps !

**EDIT**

To be perfectly fair, this is actually [explained quite well in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-your-app-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi).