# React-native Android issue: development server returned response error code: 401

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

I have an issue with React-native application i.e: The development server returned response error code: 401

[Android emulator error with React-native App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Cp3.png)

Comment: Can you show us the request you're trying to send? Looks like you need some kind of authentication. For example, does your server require a key or a username/password?

Comment: Also, as it stands, this question doesn't provide enough useful information. We can't query the server as it's on an internal `10.x.x.x` range, and we have no source code to work from. Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No my server does not require a username or password. I am running this via command prompt i.e "react-native start" to start the server and "react-native run-android" to run android app

Comment: It is a simple react-native application that Iam trying to make it run on my android phone via command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the server:

```
$ react-native run-android (launches the app on the emulator)
$ react-native start       (loads the server)
```

If this doesn't work, check that you're not running any service on that port.

You can also change the port by following this instructions:

[React Native "Could not connect to development server."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900078/react-native-could-not-connect-to-development-server/38117960#38117960)

Comment: Yes after running both, I am getting this error, as well I ran the command: "react-native start --port=8088" as the default port 8081 was busy. I have the server running and the android running. This is an issue with reac-native I think.

Comment: If you change the port for start, you also need to tell the code running on the emulator to use this port. Can't you remove whatever service is running on 8081?

Comment: Yes I guess you are correct about that. I had read that I have to change the port number else where in the code. I couldnt remove the process running on that port.I have Oracle running on that port. I will either try to change the port number in code or try to stop my oracle listener running in that port. Thanks.