# Running two React Native servers at the same time

Tags: android, react-native

I have two React Native applications which I would like to deploy to an Android emulator at the same time.

I started one on port `8081` with `react-native run-android`.

I want to start the other applications on another port. Therefore, I looked [here, where the solution shown is this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579594/reactnative-custom-port-support-for-run-android-command-mcafee-workaround)

```
react-native start --port=8082
react-native run-android
```

However, if I run that, I believe that the application running on `8081` will be killed(its server will be shut down).

So is there a way of running two applications on two different ports?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10715).

It is not that straight-forward. Before running the project you need to replace all assurances of 8081 with your desired port. Just run a search and replace it. Pay attantion that 8082 is used as well: 
`AndroidInfoHelpers.java`

```
private static final int DEBUG_SERVER_HOST_PORT = 8081;
private static final int INSPECTOR_PROXY_PORT = 8082;
```

and

`RCTInspectorDevServerHelper.mm`

```
NSNumber *inspectorProxyPort = @8082;
NSNumber *metroBundlerPort = @8081;
```

I replaced both of them in **all** the files I could find to 8091 and 8092 and worked for me.

Afterwards run:

1. `yarn start`
2. `react-native run-android`
3. after the app opens on devie with a blank screen, cmd+m or ctrl+m => Dev Settings => Debug server host & port for device => set it to localhost:
4. reload the app

things should work